# Nativescript cloud build and debug from vs code like sidekick

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, vscode-debugger

Is it possible to build a nativescript application on cloud and debug on android device from within vs code ?

I have used the NativeScript Sidekick but would prefer to build and debug inside vs code but didn't find a way around it.

I don't want to make local builds as this requires to setup the java/android sdk environment.